# how should I use output of conversion of htaccess rewrite rules to nginx rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx, webserver

I use neginx, then I need to convert htaccess rewrite rules to neginx rewrite rules. I used [this](http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/) for converting. Now I want to know how should I use of the output ?

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
```

**nginx rules:** *(the output)*

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?rt=$1 last;
}
```

how should I use of the output ?

It should be noted that I have multiple .htaccess in different folders *(3 .htaccess files in 3 different folder)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nginx, there is no such thing as an htaccess file. All of your nginx rules need to go directly into the nginx config file.

See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure

What you'll need to do because your htaccess files are in different folders is you need to wrap the rules in `location` blocks.

So for example, if the rules you posted was translated from an htaccess file in the "blogs" folder, you'd do this:

```
location /blogs/ {

    if (!-f $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }
    if (!-d $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
    }
    if ($rule_0 = "21"){
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?rt=$1 last;
    }

}
```

Comment: ah I see, and for other rules (from other htaccess file), should I create new `location` like this: `location /folder_name/ {}` in the config file, right ?

Comment: and my second (finally) question is: why the last line is not translated in the nginx rules? `ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html`

Comment: @stack yeah, if the htaccess file was in the document root, then the location would be: `location / {}` and it would be the very *last* one. As for second question, maybe the translation tool didn't know how. Try: `error_page   404  =  /error404.html;`

Comment: can I aks a new question ? *(not related to the topic)*